# Creating an Unclosable JOptionPane

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, jframe, joptionpane

I wrote a code which exactly does what I want with one problem.
It asks the user for an input from 0 to 119 and if User enters an other input it asks again because of the while loop.The only problem is that the user can always click x to close the JOptionPane if he does not want to perform the action but my purpose is to force the user enter that value.How can I accomplish that?Here is my code.

```
String y=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(p.name+ " needs to enter a position to sell")  ;
     Sposition = Integer.parseInt(y.trim());
     while(Sposition<0||Sposition>119){
          y=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(p.name+ " entered wrong value and needs to enter a position to sell")  ;
         Sposition = Integer.parseInt(y.trim()); }
```

B p is a player object which has a field name(it is not related to my question but just to clarify the code)

Answer (score 4):

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("pane");
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.show();
```

it does nothing when user clicks on (x) it.